# What are the security implications of RAMBleed?

Tags: vulnerability, memory

The [RAMBleed](https://rambleed.com/) vulnerability uses Rowhammer induced bitflips to derive contents of memory that it should not have access to. This works with ECC RAM too. It is definitely scary.

- Is this vulnerability even feasible for a real attack?
- How should operators react to this in general?
- Should Js be turned off in browsers entirely?
- What are the implications for virtualized environments?